# How to get City, State, Numeration, etc from OSM roads by Geofabrik?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, postgresql

I'm really new in this GIS world. I downloaded a shp file from Geofabrik (http://download.geofabrik.de/osm/south-america/chile.shp.zip) and imported it to Postgresql using Postgis. If I see the road table, this is the info that I get:

http://grab.by/fHa4

Looking in internet, I understood that geom can give me some geographic info that I need (lat, long per example). But, I need to know more specific information about this polyline: City, State, numeration, etc. Is this info in geom column? Or in other part in this .shp? How could I get this information?

Comment: a shape-file (extension shp) has only geometry-information. the companion dbase-file has infos like name of items, values of items etc. a shape-file is in reality at least three (or more) files: name.shp (geometry info), name.dbf (values), name.shx (index).esri has posted a detailed technical doku http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shapefiles from Geofabrik contain all information on roads as far as they are stored in the Openstreetmap geodatabase. City and state are not part of the road data. You have to look for adminstrative borders and make database queries to look inside which city or state a road is.

The road number is stored in the ref field, if it is entered by a user. For example you will find G-300 or 78. But most of city streets don't have a ref, hence the table column is empty there.